# SQL: how to replace/limit STRING field to only two possible values?

Tags: sql, string

I am working on a table where I have a STRING field with different possible values.
I want to be able with a query to:

- Keep the STRING field's value if it is equal to "demo"
- Replace it with "not demo" if it is null or equal to any other STRING.

The aim here is to create a new table with the new rules for the STRING field.

```
date         ID       FIELD  
01/01/02     57       demo
01/01/02     58       demo
02/01/02     57       null
03/01/02     57       prd
```

I am wondering how to go about doing this.

Comment: What do you want to do? Update existing table value? Or create a totally new table? Or just display the data with select?

Comment: Very odd. Do you mean `prd` above should be replaced with `not demo`. But what's expected to happen when someone inserts a new `prd` later?

Comment: I am creating a new table for a reporting dashboard to answer the needs of someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle this on the reporting side using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    date,
    ID,
    CASE WHEN FIELD = 'demo' THEN 'demo' ELSE 'not demo' END AS FIELD
FROM yourTable;
```

You *could* consider instead doing an update to your table, but besides reporting, keeping the original values in the `FIELD` column may be useful later on.